# XML parsing need help on PHP

Tags: php

I have home work for parsing XML
This is the xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
 <array>
  <dict>
   <key>code</key>
   <string>27</string>
   <key>programname</key>
   <string>Anında İstek Hattı</string>
   <key>programmername</key>
   <string>Selma Akbaş</string>
   <key>avatar</key>
   <string>selma-akbas-11.jpg</string>
  </dict>
  <dict>
   <key>code</key>
   <string>16</string>
   <key>programname</key>
   <string>Beyaz Gece</string>
   <key>programmername</key>
   <string>Okan Karakoca</string>
   <key>avatar</key>   
   <string>okan-karakoca-7.jpg</string>
  </dict>
 </array>
</plist>
```

I try to parse with this code :

```
<?php
Header('charset=utf-8');
  $test = simplexml_load_file('programlar.xml');
    foreach ($test->array as $ar) {
      foreach ($ar->dict as $dict) {
        echo($dict->key);
        echo "<br/>";
        echo($dict->string);
        echo "<br/>";
      }
    }
?>
```

The parse is done, but it get some errors.
It only show the first key-string for each dict

Can some one please fix this code?
thanks

Comment: the xml-format is unclear, however, check out xml_parse_into_struct, it's more or less of a one-liner, see examples at php.net

Comment: What errors do you get? I don't expect anyone to guess or try without you helping.

Comment: I think the problem you have is that 'string' is a php keyword.

Comment: the problem is that there are multiple key/string pairs in each dict, but the code only does one echo per dict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
Header('charset=utf-8');
$test = simplexml_load_file('programlar.xml');
foreach ($test->array as $ar) {
    foreach ($ar->dict as $dict) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($dict->key); $i++) {
            echo $dict->key[$i].'<br />';
            echo $dict->string[$i].'<br />';

    }
}
?>
```

I think this should work. Make sure you understand what is going on here before you turn it in haha. I am iterating through the "key" and "string" pairs using array style index keys, basically treating the two node sets like arrays.